# How to loop pages in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I am attempting to make a portfolio with projects and also with a little blog. I want to use 'pages' for my projects and normal posts for my blog posts. I am trying to loop the pages but I keep getting an error.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page', // set the post type to page
);
wp_reset_query();
$pages = new WP_Query($args);
if ($pages->have_posts()) { ?>

    <?php

    while ($pages->have_posts()) {
        $count++;
        $pages->the_post(); ?>

        <div>
            <article class="card post">
                <figure class="figure"
                        style="background-image: url(<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                            the_post_thumbnail_url();
                        } else {
                            bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/resources/assets/images/no-img-post.png <?php } ?>)">
                    <figcaption class="post-img d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>" title="<?php get_the_title() ?>">
                            <i class="material-icons">link</i>
                        </a>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>" title="<?php get_the_title() ?>" class="card-title">
                        <?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_title(), 60); ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="card-text">
                        <?php the_content(false, true) ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-bottom text-align-right">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>" title="Read the full article" class="btn btn-primary">
                            Read More
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>

    <?php } } ?>
```

And the error I keep getting is:

> Fatal error
>   : Uncaught Error: Call to a member function have_posts() on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\ivannikolov\wp-content\themes\port18\index.php:31 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ivannikolov\wp-includes\template-loader.php(74): include() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\ivannikolov\wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\ivannikolov\index.php(17): require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ivannikolov\wp-content\themes\port18\index.php
>   on line
>   31

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page', // set the post type to page
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query->have_posts()) {
    ?>

    <?php
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        $count++;
        ?>

        <div>
            <article class="card post">
                <figure class="figure"
                        style="background-image: url(<?php
                        if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                            the_post_thumbnail_url();
                        } else {
                            bloginfo('template_url');
                            ?>/resources/assets/images/no-img-post.png <?php } ?>)">
                    <figcaption class="post-img d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>" title="<?php get_the_title() ?>">
                            <i class="material-icons">link</i>
                        </a>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>" title="<?php get_the_title() ?>" class="card-title">
                        <?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_title(), 60); ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="card-text">
        <?php the_content(false, true) ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-bottom text-align-right">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>" title="Read the full article" class="btn btn-primary">
                            Read More
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>

    <?php
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```